# Swift: Capture Current Value of Variable

Tags: arrays, swift, variables, capture

I have ran across one post helping with this issue, but it does not seem to be very clear. I am trying to capture the value of a variable multiple times. The variable `radians` is always changing, and I want to keep the value of `radians` at the time I need it and put it into an array.

Example

```
        var initialRadian = [CGFloat]()
        var radians: CGFloat! = nil

        //Initial Radian Set
        if initialRadian.count == 0 {
            if IsHeld == true {
                initialRadian.append(radians)
            }
        }
        if initialRadian.count == 1 {
            if IsHeld == true {
                initialRadian.append(radians)
            }
        }
        if initialRadian.count == 2 {
            if IsHeld == true {
                initialRadian.append(radians)
            }
        }
```

I would like the value of `radians` to be captured when the if statement runs.

Comment: Could you provide some more context? What is the type of `radians`? Why do you have three separate if statements? Normally there should be no problem appending an instance of a structure to an array to save a copy of its value.

Comment: @MarcKhadpe `radians` is a `CGFloat`. It is constantly changing, and I want to append the value of `radians` to my array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what your code is doing. It's simple enough to save a copy of a CGFloat in an array to capture its value at a given time. Here is an example.

```
var initialRadian = [CGFloat]()
var radians: CGFloat = 7

// save the current value of radians
initialRadian.append(radians)

// modify radians
radians = 49.3

// save the modified value of radians
initialRadian.append(radians)

// modify radians again
radians = -3

// save it again
initialRadian.append(radians)

// the initialRaidan array now holds all the values of radians we saved
for val in initialRadian {
    print(val, terminator: " ") // prints "7.0 49.3 -3.0 "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think it works

```
if initialRadian.count == 0 {
        if IsHeld == true {
            initialRadian.addObject(radians)
        }
    }
   else if initialRadian[1] == nil {
        if IsHeld == true {
            initialRadian.addObject(radians)
        }
    }
    else if initialRadian[2] == nil {
        if IsHeld == true {
            initialRadian.addObject(radians)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nope, `radians` changes. I want the value of `radians` to be captured when the statement runs.

Comment: initialRadian take as NSMutableArray